# How to start developing Android application with HTML5, CSS, JavaScript and jquery?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, css

I want to develop an Android application with HTML5. Application has some basic UI with data which needs to be fetched from server.
     I have only basic knowledge of the HTML5 and CSS; But I am new to JavaScript and JQuery.

Which is essential to learn, JavaScript or JQuery? Or I need to learn both?

Any sample code for mobile application screen and request/response will be really appreciated.

Comment: It's quite obvious you haven't done any research on this. Stackoverflow is not here to do everything for you

Comment: You are wrong. Don't try to be oversmart. If you know something share it. By what you concluded that I haven't done any research. I already spent some days in learning HTML5 and CSS so I am able to design the basic UI now. I need some guidance in Javascript and JQuery that's it.

Comment: All I have to go on is your poorly researched post. It would've taken you 20 seconds to type in "cross platform mobile JavaScript" and you would've found Sencha, PhoneGap and other solutions. Spending days learning HTML and CSS isn't the same as doing 2 minutes of research about a new topic

Comment: This question pops up first for `how to make an android app with javascript` so I think this is ACTUALLY the first step in researching this. FAIL for @Bojangles try to contribute something constructive next time.

Comment: This question has lots more useful information on this, and not just rude, unhelpful comments: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19925486/best-way-to-build-native-applications-with-javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you should decide which framework you want to use. The next step is to setup environment. Let's say you want to code with PhoneGap, than you need Eclipse and Android SDK, etc. The list of software you will find in a description.

Actually in my view it is not necessary to use jQuery or its mobile version for development. Sometimes you only need to create an up to 5-6 pages app with some basic animation which is easy to make with CSS3 Transition3D.

However, when you plan to create a big app with complicated business logic, than you may need to use some framework like Sencha or Angular (it depends on your needs).

Talking about frameworks you must understand that every framework is for certain purpose only. I mean, it is ridiculous to use, for instance, knockoutJS for big apps, because the only thing it has been developed for is data binding between model and view. Moreover, in many cases you don't need a framework at all.

Anyway, first of all you should to learn JavaScript basics. I mean how it works, in which steps a code is being processed, that is a function and what in a prototype and so on. Otherwise, you will never know how to write an effective code or how to optimize your code for better performance. It is critical for a mobile devices as they are not such powerful as a desktops. Also you need to understand how a browser works (rendering, network, etc).

That's my view.

Comment: As of now I don't know anything about Sencha or Angular. Thanks for your guidance. I will explore these frameworks.

Comment: No problems! But remember that is always better to learn JavaScript before any frameworks. You may face some trivial problems related to  misunderstanding of language but not a framework. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

[You learn here javascript and jquery by simple way](http://www.codeschool.com/)

[You can build apps using html, css, javascript with phone gap](http://phonegap.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use cross mobile platform.Sencha touch is also one of the cross platform to start.

http://www.sencha.com/products/touch