# Best way to build native applications with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, mobile, cordova, native

I've been playing for a while with phonegap,
did some tests on my Android...

It's pretty nice.

My questions are:
What is the best (your favorite) framework to develop native mobile applications with web client side (HTML / JavaScript / CSS)?

How easy is to build and maintain those applications in multiplatforms (iOS / Android / BlackBerry) parallel?
Does it has many exceptions between different platforms (iOS / Android / BlackBerry)?

What are the requirements to develop my app for iOS?
Should I need a special IDE with special SDK? Must I have a Mac?

Comment: phonegap doc will answer all your doubts if you read well.
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_platforms_index.md.html

Comment: Use phonegap build to do that. You only add html + css + js and phonegap build will build app for multiple platform

Answer (score 14):

We're currently building a native iOS application using [React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/). It would be a shame if it wasn't included here.

Pros:

- React treats the DOM as an implementation detail. This made the transition over to native UI very natural.  It also removes the need for HTML/CSS when writing a native app. All you need is native components, written in JavaScript.
- Native components!  The fundamental native components have already been bridged over to JavaScript, and there is a community busy at work bringing everything else over.  The thing is, if you know or are willing to learn  some Objective C or Java, there is an [easy process](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/nativemodulesios.html) to add any native module (or third-party module) to React  Native.
- Quick iteration.  There have been over 2600 commits to the master branch since it was open-sourced in March.
- You get all of the benefits of normal React: a virtual view layer, diffing, declarative UI creation, fantastic developer experience, and a stellar community.
- You can build for multiple platforms from the same repository, reusing much of the same codebase (application logic, mostly).

Cons:

- It's still young.  There are a few features that require jimmy-rigging, a third-party library, or custom Objective-C/Java to get working.
- Some great third-party libraries that are tied to the DOM or Browser API still don't work on React Native, including React Router.
- The biggest pains have had to do with XCode and Apple's developer program, but there's no way to get around that.

*How easy is to build and maintain those applications in multi-platforms?*

React Native for Android was open-sourced on September 14th, 2015.  I haven't used it yet, but here's what I've been able to learn so far. *Update 10/21/16:* React Native for the Windows Universal Platform was announced earlier this year. That means you can now use React Native to build apps for Windows desktop, Windows phones, and even Xbox!

React Native is *not* intended to be a write once, run anywhere mentality. They adopt a learn once, write anywhere paradigm instead.  iOS is a very different platform than Android, so sincere effort needs to be put into the design for either platform. The native APIs will also be different.

So, you will end up re-writing code for native components and APIs.  However, much of your application logic can be re-used.  In fact, React-Native is organized so that you can keep both your Android and iOS applications in the same repository, so that you can re-use the same code when possible.  I think it's brilliant, but only time will tell.  [According to them](https://code.facebook.com/posts/1189117404435352/), it works well so far.

By the way, a team at Facebook [built an iOS app using React Native](https://youtu.be/PAA9O4E1IM4?t=21m), then turned around and built the Android version in three months using 87% of the same code base.

*What are the requirements to develop my app for iOS?*

Currently, you need a Mac and XCode in order to deploy.  Currently there are very few ways around this. According to [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/468) and from conversations on Slack, once deployed, you can actually develop from a Windows or Linux machine. Facebook is also working on open-sourcing all of their [Nuclide](http://nuclide.io/) packages, which, according to [their presentation at F8](https://youtu.be/X0VH78ye4yY?t=13m20s), will include tools to package and build without XCode.

Overall, React Native has been a stellar experience. It is, in my opinion, head and shoulders above anything else currently out there.  The feeling within the community is also very positive. I can only assume it will get better with time.

Comment: Thanks so much for this answer, I really appreciate the detail and it feels pretty unbiased

Comment: Isn't this just the framework? Not the way to actually build the app?

Comment: I'm not certain what you mean Arno - but React Native is a framework to create native apps in JavaScript. The framework includes tooling to develop the app, as well as build for target platforms in preparation for deployment.

Answer (score 3):

If your app is going to be very simple (for example a port of existing web app) and you need it only on one platform and it does not need integration with phone-specific features you may want to simply use a WebView on the selected platform. If your selected platform is iOS and you don't have any programming skills, you can follow these steps:

- Download xCode on your Mac,
- Download this simple web view app project: https://github.com/nomtek/iOSWebViewApp
- Open the simple web view app within xCode
- Add your HTMLs to the project
- Run it :)

Advantages of this approach:

- Simple setup
- No extra libraries to load - the application starts much faster

Answer (score 3):

This is one arena that keeps changing, and it only gets better. Googling at the moment of your interest would be the best bet. At the time of this writing, I am watching the following right now, in no particular order:

- [Enyo JS](http://enyojs.com/)
- [Sencha](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/#overview)
- [NativeScript](https://www.nativescript.org/)
- [Meteor](https://www.meteor.com/)
- [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/)
- [Appcelerator](http://www.appcelerator.com/product/)

Comment: Isn't meteor more of a general javascript framework? I know initially it was built for real time web apps.

Comment: To quote Meteor - "Meteor is a complete open source platform
for building web and mobile apps
in pure JavaScript." I agree that this might not actually generate native apps, but it's worth considering.

Answer (score 2):

these are the options

Phonegap : http://phonegap.com/

> PhoneGap is a free and open source framework that allows you to create
>   mobile apps using standardized web APIs for the platforms you care
>   about.
>   .Download the [Phonegap.](http://phonegap.com/download/)

Coronalabs : http://coronalabs.com/

> Corona SDK builds rich mobile apps for iOS, Android, Kindle and Nook.
>   Build high quality >mobile apps in a fraction of the time.

Appcelerator : http://www.appcelerator.com/

> Appcelerator is the only mobile first platform that enables enterprise
>   to create, deliver >and analyze their mobile applications.

Answer (score 1):

Phone Gap does look like your best option, if you are trying to use javascript to build a mobile app

Yes, you will need a mac, because you will need to install XCODE (https://developer.apple.com/xcode/) - apple´s own IDE.

Answer (score 0):

If you invest a bit in learning a new script language, [Coronalabs](http://coronalabs.com) would be your new weapon of choice. With it you can build native (cross-platform) apps and you can use a webview to add your HTML/CSS/Javascript stuff if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment React Native is the best option for creating mobile apps in JavaScript.

Here are my top 3 reasons:

1. Very active development and updates - After all it originated at FB
2. Negligible learning curve
3. Great online resources

I was able to write a small but functional app without previous React Native experience and even deploy it to the Google Play Store all within 2 days.

Also one great benefit that i see with React Native is that you can "eject" your app at any point in time and continue to work on it in Android Studio or XCode. This could be a big relief in projects that start simple but could get complex over a period of time.

Here is short tutorial I put together while building my first react native app for Android: 
http://geekycentral.com/creating-a-native-android-app-using-javascript-hello-react-native/