# Could anyone talk about how React Native runs, why someone says its performance is better than other hybrid framework

Tags: reactjs, react-native, hybrid-mobile-app

All:

I am thinking of starting React Native, one reason is many people talk its performance is better than other Hybrid Framework, but I am wondering how React Native make it faster in Mobile, I thought all hybrid app is like a web app run in a webview, is the way React Native uses different from Cordova? **Could anyone talk about the procedure how React Native is turned into a mobile app?**

Thanks

Comment: This question might be a bit too broad and general for SO. React's own video's [e.g. here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XQM0K6YG18s) explain why and how performance is better, and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KVZ-P-ZI6W4&list=PLb0IAmt7-GS1cbw4qonlQztYV1TAW0sCr) how react native is different from web app.

Comment: @wintvelt Thanks for helpful links, I will watch those.

Comment: Performance isn't the only benefit.  If you're interested in other reasons, see my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19925486/best-way-to-build-native-applications-with-javascript/31680267#31680267).

Comment: @JacobTurner Thanks, one question: how do you get the link to your answer in that page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the other comments. Your question is a bit broad, but the short of it I think is that hybrid apps rely on the WebView, so they're performance is limited by the browser's performance, which is of course single threaded. Getting 60fps animations is a constant struggle for Hybrid apps, though they're getting better all the time both in terms of the browser's capabilities and technique.

React Native bridges to native components, so you get native performance characteristics. Things like calculating the view are offloaded acync to separate threads, so the user's experience is never blocked.

Here's a useful list of other benefits...
[WHY REACT NATIVE IS THE BEST SOLUTION WE HAVE SO FAR FOR NATIVE MOBILE DEVELOPMENT](https://li.st/l/31383138-3733-0000-0000-000000000000)

sorry for the all caps... that's the actual title of the list :/

Comment: Thanks for reply. I think you point out the crucial part - the native separated thread, this is a diff way from browser works, now I get it.

Comment: Awesome, glad to help :)

Comment: so React Native is more like Appcelerator Titanium?

Comment: @Kuan yes and no, but mostly no. Though they do share a common language (javascript), they're actually quite different in their approach.

Comment: Thanks, so which will be your recommendation if I want to build a mobile app which shows data visualization( by data viz I mean data processing and html/SVG elements operation according to user interaction )?

Comment: based on those requirements alone, I'd think you'd have an easier time with a hybrid framework such as ionic since you're naturally dealing with html/svg. You'll want to check what the svg support is for your target mobile browsers. I'm not too familiar on that front, but I'd expect you'll find decent support. If html is not a firm requirement, react-native could work still. See: https://github.com/brentvatne/react-native-svg

Comment: Thanks. I tried Ionic a little bit before, did not feel very well, just like when I learnt Bootstrap( still not comfortable with it now ), so many things to remember and a lot of confuse raised up. Anyway, another thing that I think very important is: Could you help by giving a check list of FrontEnd developer qualification, I am trying to get a FrontEnd/Mobile App entry level job, but no idea which skills are most crucial can catch the eye of most HR/Recruit Manager?

Comment: @Kuan, I agree that hybrid apps generally feel sluggish compared to native apps, which is why I personally prefer react-native. However Angular 2 + NativeScript looks incredibly promising to me as well. There are [plenty of articles out there](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=what%20every%20front%20end%20dev%20should%20know) to guide you on your journey, so I won't try to reiterate since they've already articulated it far better than I could. My advice, build apps... lots of apps... and share them via github. Good luck!

Comment: thanks, one thing I am concerning about NG2+NativeScritp is: Even Nativescritp is under Apache2.0, but many release item on its official site requires pay, I kinda worrying its future popularity will be affected?

Comment: What are your concerns with Apache 2 licensing? Seems fairly liberal to me https://tldrlegal.com/license/apache-license-2.0-(apache-2.0). I don't see anything on their website that requires pay either, so I'm confused on that point as well.

Comment: On the roadmap page, it lists many UI from Telerik, which ask for a price. https://www.nativescript.org/roadmap

Comment: I must not be looking in the same place as you because I'm totally missing it. It is, however, a common business model to make the core open source and freely available, while building pay-for-premium-services around the core. Are you still concerned about Apache 2.0 licensing?

Comment: Yes, there is no budget for any of them from my team, so I have to make sure there are no-charged supports and module as many as possible.