# Building android app with javascript/angular

Tags: android, angular

I know you need to use Java to build native applications for Android, however what is the best way to build websites and (or) native apps using javascript frameworks like Angular?

Comment: "Best" way or just one way? Have you tried searching for "native android javascript"? For example [NativeScript](http://docs.nativescript.org/angular/tutorial/ng-chapter-0)

Comment: Possible duplicate. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19925486/best-way-to-build-native-applications-with-javascript

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to build limited Android apps using javascript running in a WebView. See [AppBuilder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.serakont.appbuilder).

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Ionic Framework](https://ionicframework.com/docs/). It is one of the most popular Javascript-based framework for iOS/ Android App Development.